# PHP find equal variables

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to easily check if the values of multiple variables are equal? For example, in the code below I have 10 values, and it's cumbersome to use the equal sign to check if they're all equal.

```
 <?
  foreach($this->layout as $l): 
  $long1=$l['long1_campaignid'];    
  $long2=$l['long2_campaignid']; 
  $long3=$l['long3_campaignid'];    
  $long4=$l['long4_campaignid']; 
  $long5=$l['long5_campaignid'];    
  $long6=$l['long6_campaignid'];    
  $long7=$l['long7_campaignid'];    
  $long8=$l['long8_campaignid'];    
  $long9=$l['long9_campaignid'];    
  $long10=$l['long10_campaignid'];
  endforeach;
 ?>
```

for example
if $long1=3,$long2=7,$long3=3,$long4=7,$long5=3 etc,

i need to retrieve $long1=$long3=$long5 and $long2=$long4

Comment: So you want to write `$long1 == $long2 == $long3 == $long4 == $long5 == $long6 == $long7 == $long8 == $long9 == $long10` more succinctly?

Comment: If you explain more about the problem it might have a different solution than the one you are thinking of

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "retrieve `$long1=$long3=$long5`"? I understand that these three variables are equal in value, but I don't understand what result you're trying to get from them.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
<?
  foreach($this->layout as $l): 
  $m = array_unique($l);
  if (count($m) === 1) {
      echo 'All of the values are the same<br>';
  }
  endforeach;
?>
```

I assuming that you are looking to see if all of the values in the array are the same. So to do this I call [`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicates from the array. If all of the values of the array are the same this will leave us with an array of one element. So I check for this and if it is true then all of the values are the same.

Comment: Thans for your reply, but it's not what I am looking for.if $long1=3,$long2=7,$long3=3,$long4=7,$long5=3 etc, i need to retrieve $long1=$long3=$long5 and $long2=$long4

Comment: Then you will need to do a better job explaining what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The example showed at the question is about "**grouping**" not directly about "find equal variables".

I think this  simple "grouping without change the order" algorithm  is the answer... Other algorithms using `sort()` are also easy to implement with PHP.

```
<?
  foreach($this->layout as $l) {
     $m = array();
     foreach($1 as $k=>$v) // keys 'longX' and values
        if (array_key_exists($v,$m)) $m[$v][] = $k; 
        else                         $m[$v]   = array($k);
     foreach ($m as $val=>$keys)
        if (count($keys)>1) echo "<br/> have SAME values: ".join(',',$keys)
  }
?>
```

### About "find equal variables"

Another  (simple) code, see Example #2 at [PHP man of  array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
<?
  $m = array_unique($this->layout);
  $n = count($m);
  if ($n == 1)
      echo 'All of the values are the exactly the same';
  elseif ($n>0)
      echo 'Different values';
  else 
      echo 'No values';
?>
```

The "equal criteria" perhaps need some filtering at strings, to normalize spaces, lower/upper cases, etc. Only the use of this "flexible equal" justify a loop. Example:

```
<?
  $m = array();
  foreach($this->layout as $l) 
      $m[trim(strtolower($1))]=1;
  $n = count(array_keys($m));
  if ($n == 1)
      echo 'All of the values are the exactly the same';
  elseif ($n>0)
      echo 'Different values';
  else 
      echo 'No values';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If @John Conde's answer is not what you are looking for and you want to check for one or more of the same values in the collection, you could [`sort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) the array and then loop through it, keeping the last value and comparing it to the current value.